# Very slow mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a very simple MySQL table that is running extremely slow, and I cannot figure out why.

The structure is:

```
id               int(11)        (Primary Key)        
username         varchar(64)    (Index)              
password         varchar(64)                 
pws              varchar(16)                 
default_password varchar(32)                 
session_id       varchar(64)                 
license_number   int(10)        (Index)          
contact_name     varchar(64)                 
phone            varchar(16)                 
first_login_date datetime                
last_login_date  datetime                
status           tinyint(4)              
test_mode        tinyint(4)              
email            varchar(64)                 
email_verified   tinyint(4)
```

There are only 80 something rows in the table, yet the following query took *67 seconds*!!

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `username` ASC
```

Pretty much any operation on this table is outrageously slow. What am I doing wrong, or where should I start digging?

*As a side not, I have another, more complicated table, with 20,000 rows, that runs very fast.*

**UPDATE...Repairing the database and optimizing helped with the select. It seems updates are extremely slow though, and then slowing down selects...

```
$this->db->update( "UPDATE users SET session_id='' WHERE id=:userid", array( ":userid" => $this->getUserId() ) );
```

Here is the PHP Database code I am using:

```
class Database extends PDO
{

    public function __construct($DB_TYPE, $DB_HOST, $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS)
    {

        $this->handleDB = new PDO($DB_TYPE.':host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
        $this->handleDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }

public function update($sql, $array = array())
    {
        $sth = $this->handleDB->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {


            if(is_int($value)){
                $sth->bindValue("$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }else{
                $sth->bindValue("$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }



        }

        $sth->execute();

        return $sth->rowCount();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try running `check table users;` to see if there are any issues with the table. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html

Comment: I'm gonna guess there's another process with a lock on that table, and your manual queries might be waiting their turn. In what kind of application is this?

Comment: above and or ANALYZE TABLE `users`; REPAIR TABLE `users`. `EXPLAIN` in front of the query could show something useful

Comment: There's also `optimize table users;`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: has the table always only had 80 rows?, if a lot are deleted, delete and recreating the indexes can help

Comment: I have repaired, and optimized the table. It will return results quickly until I make any update to the data... ( eg: $this->db->update( "UPDATE users SET session_id='' WHERE id=:userid", array( ":userid" => $this->getUserId() ) ); );

I added the DB code for the update, in case I am doing something wrong there...



@laketua It is a large custom website / app.

Answer (score 1):

You can check two things, if you are running queries from Client machine check your network speed to the server. If query is running slow on Server you can check in Slow query log on Mysql server.  Second, you try to recreate index on the table. Try check table, repair table commands on MySql.